# What does @class do in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone please explain me what does `@class` declaration do in Objective-C and what are the cases in which we should use this declaration?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It’s a forward declaration. It essentially tells the compiler that there’s a class of that name. I use it in the interface declarations:

```
@class Foo;
@interface Bar : NSObject {
    Foo *someFoo;
}
@end
```

Of course you could import the header for `Foo` instead:

```
#import "Foo.h"
@interface Bar : NSObject {
    Foo *someFoo;
}
@end
```

But if `someFoo` is not exposed to users of `Bar`, they would import an extra header file that’s of no use to them. With the `@class` declaration the users of `Bar` see no extra import, because `Foo.h` will be imported in the implementation file of `Bar`.

Comment: I still dont understand it fully and i know its an old post but and example would be good. What do you mean by "Users of Bar", classes that will have bar as an object in them? Imean in your example Foo is an object in Bar. So whast the difference between #import and @class in this situation?

Comment: Indeed a wonderful explanation. I faced a situation earlier where I should have used it. Anyways, now I certainly can. :)

Comment: @zoul...I am using a forward declaration in .h file; however, I have to import the header file in the .m file or it gives an error, "Receiver type " *** " for class message is a forward declaration". So, why shouldn't I import the file in the header file, instead of making a forward declaration? This way I could reuse it in the .m file as well.

Comment: If you have an instance variable of type Foo and import Foo.h in your public header, anyone who uses this header will also import Foo.h, although they may not need to know about Foo at all (it could be a private variable, for example).

Comment: I am pretty sure you work/worked at Google by looking at that example

Answer (score 26):

it is called a forward declaration.

you use this directive to tell the compiler that there is an objc class with the name specified. your other options are to include the interface, or use id for variables or types.

this is helpful to minimize dependencies. i use them whenever i can to minimize dependencies, and significantly reduce build times.

it's the same as in c and c++:

```
struct mon_struct;
namespace MON { class mon_class; }
```

Comment: +1 for tipping that this should be preferred in order to reduce build times.

Answer (score 11):

hope this will help little more

Above answer already state almost every thing , i would like to add some thing on it.

The `@class Foo`  is a forward declaration of the Foo class. It’s like telling the compiler, foo class exists So don't bother about it right now.

Note:- Class declaration becomes very critical when both class need each other. if we do  usual #import statement then, we would have an endless loop of imports and Compilers don’t like endless loops. So we use `@class Classname`.

Answer (score 2):

`@class` is used for creating forward declaration of any class. If you're creating any class that's implementation is unknown to you then you can do this using `@class` compiler directive.

You can implement this class when the implementation is known to you.