# iOS - Property 'view' cannot be found in forward class object

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller

I'm just starting out with Objective -C. My code keeps giving the error: Property 'view' cannot be found in forward class object 'startPageViewController'. I can't work out what it is! Here is my code.

startPageViewController.h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class searchResultsViewController;
@class startPageViewController;

@interface startPageViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)switchViews:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField * searchterm;
@property (nonatomic, retain) startPageViewController *blueViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) searchResultsViewController *yellowViewController;

@end
```

startPageViewController.m -

```
#import "startPageViewController.h"
#import "searchResultsViewController.h"

@class searchResultsViewController;
@class startPageViewController;

@interface startPageViewController ()

@end

@implementation startPageViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)switchViews:(id)sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview]; // <-- Error here
    [self.view insertSubview:_yellowViewController.view atIndex:0];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setSearchterm:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

searchResultsViewController.h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface searchResultsViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *googleResults;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *bingResults;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *amazonResults;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *ebayResults;

@end
```

searchResultsViewController.m -

```
#import "searchResultsViewController.h"

@interface searchResultsViewController ()

@end

@implementation searchResultsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *googleUrlAddress = @"http://www.google.com/";
    NSURL *googleUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:googleUrlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *googleRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:googleUrl];
    [_googleResults loadRequest:googleRequestObj];
    // --------------------
    NSString *bingUrlAddress = @"http://www.bing.com/";
    NSURL *bingUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:bingUrlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *bingRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:bingUrl];
    [_bingResults loadRequest:bingRequestObj];
    // --------------------
    NSString *amazonUrlAddress = @"http://www.amazon.com/";
    NSURL *amazonUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:amazonUrlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *amazonRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:amazonUrl];
    [_amazonResults loadRequest:amazonRequestObj];
    // --------------------
    NSString *ebayUrlAddress = @"http://www.ebay.com/";
    NSURL *ebayUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:ebayUrlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *ebayRequestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:ebayUrl];
    [_ebayResults loadRequest:ebayRequestObj];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setGoogleResults:nil];
    [self setBingResults:nil];
    [self setAmazonResults:nil];
    [self setEbayResults:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

Thanks in advance!

By the way, nothing too complex please. I'm only 12. :)

Comment: Where are you using `blueViewController.view`? Cant see that in code. You should post `blueViewController` class. Another thing is you should always use Capital letter for class names as `BlueViewController`. `blueViewController` represents variable names.

Comment: beyond syntax, removing self.view in the switchViews method (then adding a subview to the now orphaned view) looks like a mistake.

Comment: Just noticed 'I'm only 12'...  You're writing code at 12, i'll bet you can handle plenty of complex stuff.  kudos for great start! :-)

Comment: Looks like `blueViewController` is the object of same class. You should change your `switchViews` method. Right now you are removing self.view which you shouldn't do there. Just add the other view on top of self.view.

Comment: @danh And asking better questions than some college students.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the extraneous `@class` declarations in the `startPageViewController.m` file. Those are hiding the full definition you get from the `#import` statements.

You should only have `@class` forward declarations in a .h file (like you are already doing).

One other suggestion - It is standard practice in many programming languages, including Objective-C, that class names begin with an uppercase letter. Variables and method names should begin with lowercase letters. Doing this, along with everyone else, makes code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you're including the header files you don't need the forwarding declarations.  So you can remove:

```
@class searchResultsViewController;
@class startPageViewController;
```

Comment: i think you're right that these are unnecessary, but would they generate a compiler error?  i just tried adding an excess @class MyClass into MyClass.m and .h, and these caused neither compiler warning nor error.

Comment: You use the class forwarding declarations in your interface  (.h) file when you want to reference a class before it has been defined.  It's not used in the implementation (.m) file.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904663/what-does-class-do-in-objective-c

Comment: Yes, I understand.  And you point out correctly that they are extraneous in the .m.  But OP is trying to solve a compiler error that I don't think your suggestion solves.  (The declarations are unneeded but harmless).